# Calculate the divergence of the polar coordinate vector field $\partial_\phi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I have to solve this problem:

> $v=\partial_\phi$ on $M=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash{0}$ where the components of $v$ are in polar coordinates.
>
> Calculate the divergence of $v$.

Even with the help of comments and answers I have problems solving this. Can someone give me a full solution? (I am not trying to dodge working by myself!)

Comment: what do you mean by 'written out'?

Comment: Sounds like you are writing vectors [as derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_derivations). Polar coordinates $\rho, \phi$ on $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ induce the basis $\partial_{\rho},\partial_{\phi}$ of its tangent bundle. Here $\partial_{\phi}$ is shorthand for $\partial/\partial \phi$.

Comment: you can intuitively think of $\partial_{\phi}$ as like the $\hat\phi$ unit vector in more elementary treatments of polar coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$, except in the case of more general manifolds, really it's an 'assignment' of $\hat\phi$ in every tangent space in a consistent way (this is what vector fields are)

Comment: @A.P. Ok. I already thought so. I have to calculate the divergence of $v$. I know how to do this with explicit vector fields. But how would I calculate $div\, v$?

Comment: @kaos: this *is* an explicit vector field... so I'm not entirely sure what you mean :-)

Comment: @oldrinb So this is nothing else than $v= (-\sin \phi, \cos \phi)$?

Comment: @kaos In what basis is that coordinate tuple written in? I ask because $\partial_\phi$ is not in general a unit vector--this is a major difference between how a basis is chosen in higher mathematics versus elementary vector calculus.

Comment: @Muphrid The only thing the problem states is that the components of $v$ are in polar coordinates..

Comment: You've said you have a problem with the notation. What is the actual question you're being asked?

Comment: Ok, it seems like my problem is lying deeper than just the notation. Im going to change my question to fit what I have to do.

Comment: @kaos: But divergence is usually computed on 3D, unless you have a different definition that I am not aware of.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is the divergence. What is the definition of divergence that you should use?  Are you given an expression that should compute the divergence in polar coordinates?

Comment: We defined the divergence as
$$ \mathrm{div} u = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathrm{det} g}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(\sqrt{\mathrm{det} g} u^j)$$

For cartesian coordinates this boiles down to 

$$\mathrm{div} \, u = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^j}$$

Comment: Instead of changing a question so radically---in this case, from a conceptual question to a specific computation---it would have been better to post the new question ("Calculate the divergence...) as a separate question. Gary's answer answer and mine are both sensible answers to the original question, but now someone else needing help with the original question will not find those answers, and those answers probably will not help much anyone with the new question.

Comment: I will do that next time the problem occurs. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the definition of divergence

$$\text{div } u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} (u^i \sqrt{g})$$

where $g$ here means the determinant of the metric and summation over $i$ is implied.

Here, our vector field is $u = \partial_\phi$.  More clearly, write it out in components, in terms of the basis vectors $\partial_r$ and $\partial_\phi$.  That is

$$u = u^r \partial_r + u^\phi \partial_\phi$$

That is, $u^r = 0$ and $u^\phi = 1$. These are the numbers that will stand in for $u^i$ in the expression for divergence.

Finally, with $g = r^2$, we get

$$\text{div } u = \frac{1}{r} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (0 \cdot r) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} (1 \cdot r) \right] = 0$$

which is zero.

Comment: Thank you. I cant believe I struggled so much with this. Thanks for your patience. In the next problem I have to do the same using cylindrical coordinates with $v=\partial_z+2\partial_\phi$ and $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|0<z<1, x^2+y^2=z^2\}$. I calculated div $v=0$ with the help of your answer. Could you check if thats correct?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that we can just as well use the coordinate definition to give a general formula for divergence in polar coordinates:
$$\text{div } u = \frac{1}{r} \partial_r (r u^r) + \frac{1}{r} \partial_{\phi} u^{\phi}.$$

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** The original question was [changed radically](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1355217/revisions) after this answer was posted. The question was (paraphrasing),

> In polar coordinates $(r, \phi)$, how do I interpret the vector field $\partial_{\phi}$ and write it in Cartesian coordinates?

---

Assuming that $\phi$ is the angular coordinate (typically it is denoted $\theta$), it is the vector field whose action on functions $f(r, \phi)$ is given by the partial derivative with respect to $\phi$, that is, the instantaneous change $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$ of $f$ under anticlockwise rotation.

If the differentiated function $f$ is given as a function of $x$ and $y$, some elementary trigonometry gives that the value of $f$ at the point given by rotating $(x, y)$ anticlockwise by an angle $\theta$ is
$$f(x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta, x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta),$$
and the instantaneous change $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$ of $f$ under anticlockwise rotation is, by definition, the derivative of this quantity with respect to $\theta$ at $\theta = 0$, namely,
$$\left.\frac{d}{d \theta} \right\vert_{\theta = 0} f(x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta, x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta) = -y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.$$
But this is just the action of the vector field
$$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad \color{#bf0000}{\boxed{-y \partial_x + x \partial_y}} \qquad (\ast)$$
on the function $f$, so $(\ast)$ is the Cartesian representation of $\partial_{\phi}$.

This computation both hides and resolves a notational abuse and a corresponding technical complication: The expression $\partial_{\phi}$ simply denotes a coordinate vector field in a particular coordinate system, and, strictly speaking, a coordinate system should give unique coordinates for each point in the region the coordinates cover. On the other hand, there is no continuous choice of polar angular coordinate on all of $\Bbb R^2$, or even all of $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$, so in order to talk about coordinate vector field $\partial_{\phi}$, we must really restrict our polar coordinates to some (say, open) subset $U \subset \Bbb R^2$ on which there *is* a continuous choice of angular coordinate. For any such choice, the coordinate vector field $\partial_{\phi}$ is only defined on $U$, rather than all of $\Bbb R^2$.

On the other hand, the above computation shows that, no matter our choice of $U$, $\partial_{\phi}$ is the restriction of the vector field $\color{#bf0000}{-y \partial_x + x \partial_y}$, which *is* defined on all of $\Bbb R^2$. Because of this, it is suggestive, convenient, and abusive to use the more compact notation $\partial_{\phi}$ for this vector field.

---

**Edit** With the expression $(\ast)$ in hand, it's easy to compute the divergence (though this is certainly slower than using the expression for the divergence in general coordinates given in the comments):

$$\text{div } \partial_{\phi} = \text{div} (-y \partial_x + x \partial_x) = \frac{d}{dx}(-y) + \frac{d}{dy}(x) = 0 .$$

Answer (score 2):

$\partial \phi$ is just the vector often written as $\frac {\partial}{\partial \phi}$. It has a dual $d\phi$, so that $d\phi(\partial \phi)=1$. It is used with polar coordinates $(r, \phi)$, and there you have an orthogonal basis for the tangent space at every point given by $(\partial r, \partial \phi)=(\frac {\partial }{\partial r}, \frac {\partial}{\partial \phi} )$. For a plot, see:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html

(Ignore the z-coordinate, or take a fixed slice $z=z_0$ and draw $\partial r , \partial \phi$ in the same direction as the $r, \phi$ coordinates in the plot.)

Basically, $\partial r$ at a point $(x,y)$ is drawn by a line of length $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ from the origin to the point $(x,y)$ and $\partial \phi$ is drawn perpendicular to $\partial r$.

EDIT: Like Travis pointed out, this is an orthogonal, but not orthonormal basis.

EDIT2: This post was intended to answer the question before it was edited, which was, as I understood, how to plot the vector field $(\partial \phi)$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting, too, that while the basis is orthogonal, it is not orthonormal, as $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ is not a unit vector field.

Comment: Good point, let me edit it in.